# Example of function such that integral of $|x(t)|$ is $<+\infty$, and integral of $|x(t)|^2$ is $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I'm trying to look for an example of a function such that:

$$
1.
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty }^{+ \infty }} \lvert x(t) \rvert \, dt < + \infty $$

$$
2.
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty }^{+ \infty }} \lvert x(t) \rvert^2 \, dt = + \infty
$$

Thank you for your willingness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x(t)=\frac 1 {\sqrt t}$ for $0<t<1$ and $0$ for all other values of $t$.

Comment: excellent solution.

Comment: Are the extremes of integration $0^+$ and $1$ when I consider the piece in $0<t<1$; maybe it's better to write $0<t \leq 1$?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi It  makes no difference. Integral from $0$ to $1$ does not depend on whether you are including the end points or not.

Comment: ...but the domain of $1/ \sqrt{t}$ is $t > 0$, not $\geq$. My professor said that the extremes of integration must be inside the domain of the function, not inside the domain of the primitive function.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi I think you did not get the definition of $x(t)$ correctly. The function is defined on the entire real line: I have defined $x(t)$ to be $0$ when $x \notin (0,1)$. So the domain is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you @KaviRamaMurthy, I forgot a piece; I'm sorry.

Comment: can you see this dual question please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3124643/example-of-function-integral-of-xt-is-infinity-and-integral-of-xt2

Answer (score 2):

You have asked two questions now looking for examples of functions with certain properties with respect to integrability or square integrability.  Let me provide a slightly more general way of thinking about these problems.

> **Definition:** Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.  The *$L^p$-norm* of $f$ is defined by
>   $$ \|f\|_p := \left( \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x \right)^{1/p}. $$

In this question, you are looking for an example of a function $f$ such that
$$ \|f\|_1 < +\infty \qquad\text{and}\qquad \|f\|_2 = +\infty, \tag{1}$$
while [this other question you asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3124643/example-of-function-integral-of-xt-is-infinity-and-integral-of-xt2) is looking for examples of a function $f$ such that
$$ \|f\|_1 = +\infty \qquad\text{and}\qquad \|f\|_2 < +\infty. \tag{2}$$
These two questions are very closely linked.

---

Generally speaking, there are two features of functions which will tend to make them hard to integrate.  These are "spikes" and "tails".

**Spikes**

By a "spike," I mean that the function blows up somewhere in its domain.  For example, the function $x \mapsto 1/x$ blows up around 0.  Suppose that the function $f$ has a "spike} at $x=a$.  That is, suppose that
$$ \lim_{x\to a} |f(x)| = +\infty. $$
Then on some neighborhood of $a$, we will have $|f(x)|>1$, which implies that the function will be dominated by its square.  More rigorously, there exists some $r > 0$ such that
$$ 1 < |f(x)| < |f(x)|^2 \qquad\text{for all $x \in (a-r, a+r)$}. $$
But then
$$ \int_{a-r}^{a+r} |f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x < \int_{a-r}^{a+r} |f(x)|^2\,\mathrm{d}x. $$
The intuition of this is that "spikes" become less integrable as you increase $p$.  That is, if $f$ is "spikey," then (roughly speaking)
$$ \|f\|_p < \|f\|_q $$
whenever $p < q$.  So in order to find a function which satisfies (1), we should be looking for a "spikey" function (which is also not too heavy tailed, as described below).

**Tails**

If a function $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and we are to have any hope that
$$ \|f\|_p < \infty $$
for some value of $p$, then it must be the case that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x) = 0$.  Otherwise, the integral will diverge.  This is a description of the asymptotic behaviour, or the "tails", of the function.  Since the function goes to zero at infinity, there must be some number $M$ so large that $|x| > M$ implies that $|f(x)| < 1$.  But then
$$ 1 > |f(x)| > |f(x)|^2 \qquad \text{for all $|x|>M$.} $$
But then (working only on the right half-line)
$$ \int_{M}^{+\infty} |f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x > \int_{M}^{+\infty} |f(x)|^2\,\mathrm{d}x. $$
Here, the intuition is that "tails" become more integrable as $p$ is increased.  That is, if $f$ is "heavy tailed", then (again, roughly speaking)
$$ \|f\|_p > \|f\|_q $$
whenever $p < q$.  So in order to find a function which satisfies (2), we should be looking for a "heavy tailed" function (which is also not too spikey).

---

My usual goto example of a function which is both spikey and heavy tailed is the function
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{x}. $$
This function has a spike at zero.  Indeed, we have
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \left| \frac{1}{x} \right| \,\mathrm{d}x
\ge \int_{0}^{1}  \frac{1}{x}  \,\mathrm{d}x
= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\varepsilon}^{1} \frac{1}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x
= \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} \left[ \log(1) - \log(\varepsilon) \right]
= +\infty. $$
This function is also heavy tailed, since
$$ \int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x
= \lim_{M\to+\infty} \int_{1}^{M} \frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
= \lim_{M\to+\infty} \left[ \log(M) - \log(1) \right]
= +\infty. $$

On the other hand, this function isn't "too spikey."  In particular, define the function $g$ so that
$$ g(x)^2 = \frac{1}{x} \chi_{(0,1]}(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x} & \text{if $x \in (0,1]$, and} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} $$
In other words, we are defining $g$ so that it is $x \mapsto 1/x$ is "spikier" than $g$.  Since increasing the power of a spikey function makes it less integrable, decreasing the power should make it more integrable.  Cleaning up the notation above, we have
$$ g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \chi_{(0,1]}(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} & \text{if $x \in (0,1]$, and} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} $$
We have already shown that
$$ \|g\|_2 = \int_{0}^{1} \left|\frac{1}{x} \right| \,\mathrm{d}x = +\infty. $$
On the other hand
$$ \|g\|_1
= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x
= \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} \int_{\varepsilon} x^{-1/2}\,\mathrm{d}x
= \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} \left[ \frac{1}{2} 1^{1/2} - \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon^{1/2} \right]
= \frac{1}{2} < +\infty. $$
Therefore $g$ is an example of of a function which satisfies (1).

On the other hand, $x \mapsto 1/x$ has a heavy tail, so we can flatten that out by taking higher powers.  So define $h$ by
$$
h(x) = \frac{1}{x} \chi_{[1,\infty)}(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x} & \text{if $x \ge 1$, and} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} $$
It was already shown above that
$$ \|h\|_1 = +\infty. $$
On the other hand,
$$ \|h\|_2
= \int_{1}^{+\infty} \left| \frac{1}{x} \right|^2 \,\mathrm{d}x
= \lim_{M\to+\infty} \int_{1}^{M} x^{-2} \,\mathrm{d}x
= \lim_{M\to+\infty} \left[ -M^{-1} + 1^{-1} \right]
= 1 < +\infty. $$
Therefore $h$ is an example of a function which satisfies (2).

---

**Summary**

The function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by the formula
$$ g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \chi_{(0,1]}(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} & \text{if $x \in (0,1]$, and} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise,} \end{cases} $$
satisfies (1).

The function $h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by the formula
$$ h(x) = \frac{1}{x} \chi_{[1,\infty)}(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x} & \text{if $x \ge 1$, and} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise,} \end{cases} $$
satisfies (2).

Comment: Hello @XanderHenderson, thank you so much for your extremily clear explanation; it's very very useful to understand the problem.